# Regex to match only 1 digit between 0 to 2

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will have thoese properies:

- Only one digit. (no more, no less)
- The digit can only be 0 or 1 or 2.

The second property is easy `(0|1|2)` or `[0-2]`, but I cant limit it to one digit.

Thank you.

Comment: `[0-2]` will only match exactly one character. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you just need the start and end anchors?  (e.g. `^[0-2]$`)

Comment: Does the word / entire string have to be only one digit or do you want to match all single digits within a string?

Comment: @Biffen Thank you sir

Comment: Ron, There's no need to be snippy with people who are trying to help you.  What Biffen said is true.  You still haven't answered @Robin's question, which is a very critical one for understanding what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET (as well as plenty of other regex implementations), the methods to for regex matching don't check whether the complete string matches, they check whether any substring matches. By its logic, `"awffowhf35lhns1afwa"` is a match, because it contains a substring `"1"`.

To only allow whole string matches, you can use the `^` and `$` special characters to require positioning at the beginning and the end of a string: `^[0-2]$`.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading in that it makes it sound like a peculiarity of .NET's regex implementation.  I would say that is the case with almost all regex flavors.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Reworded to hopefully avoid being misleading, but I avoided "almost all" since I don't actually know that, and one that I use frequently nowadays, admittedly an uncommon one, does do complete string matching.

Comment: @hvd Solved my problem. i will accept the answer when I can (in 2 min)